# Why does the function return early?

Tags: concurrency, go

I've just started learning go, and have been working through the tour. The last exercise is to edit a web crawler to crawl in parallel and without repeats.

Here is the link to the exercise: http://tour.golang.org/#70

Here is the code. I only changed the crawl and the main function. So I'll just post those to keep it neat.

```
    // Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
    // pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
    var used = make(map[string]bool)
    var urlchan = make(chan string)
    func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
        // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
        // Done: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
        // This implementation doesn't do either:
        done := make(chan bool)
        if depth <= 0 {
            return
        }
        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("\nfound: %s %q\n\n", url, body)
        go func() {
            for _, i := range urls {
                urlchan <- i
            }
            done <- true
        }()
        for u := range urlchan {
            if used[u] == false {
                used[u] = true
                go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
            }
            if <-done == true {
                break
            }
        }
        return
    }

    func main() {
        used["http://golang.org/"] = true
        Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    }
```

The problem is that when I run the program the crawler stops after printing

```
    not found: http://golang.org/cmd/
```

This only happens when I try to make the program run in parallel. If I have it run linearly then all the urls are found correctly.

Note: If I am not doing this right (parallelism I mean) then I apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Be careful with goroutine.
- Because when the main routine, or `main()` func, returns, all others go routine would be killed immediately.
- Your `Crawl()` seems like recursive, however it is not, which means it would return immediately, not awaiting for other `Crawl()` routines. And you know that if the first `Crawl()`, called by `main()`, returns, the `main()` func regards its mission fulfilled.
- What you could do is to let `main()` func wait until the last `Crawl()` returns. The `sync` package, or a `chan` would help.
- You could probably take a look at the last solution of [this](https://gist.github.com/2317744), which I did months ago:

  ```
  var store map[string]bool

  func Krawl(url string, fetcher Fetcher, Urls chan []string) {
      body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
      if err != nil {
          fmt.Println(err)
      } else {
          fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
      }
      Urls <- urls
  }

  func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
      Urls := make(chan []string)
      go Krawl(url, fetcher, Urls)
      band := 1
      store[url] = true // init for level 0 done
      for i := 0; i < depth; i++ {
          for band > 0 {
              band--
              next := <- Urls
              for _, url := range next {
                  if _, done := store[url] ; !done {
                      store[url] = true
                      band++
                      go Krawl(url, fetcher, Urls)
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      return
  }

  func main() {
      store = make(map[string]bool)
      Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
  }
  ```

Comment: yep http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs&feature=player_detailpage#t=442s here is robe pike explaining goroutines and main